# Remove parts of a string with PHP

Tags: php, string, split

I have an input box that tells uers to enter a link from imgur.com
I want a script to check the link is for the specified site but I'm not sue how to do it?

The links are as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYnCi.jpg
Please note that after the /, the text may vary e.g. not be a jpg but the main domain is always http://i.imgur.com/.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks, Josh.(Novice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(preg_match('#^http\:\/\/i\.imgur.com\/#', $_POST['url']))
    echo 'Valid img!';
else
    echo 'Img not valid...';
?>
```

Where $_POST['url'] is the user input.

I haven't tested this code.

Answer (score 3):

Try [parse_url()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
try {
    if (!preg_match('/^(https?|ftp)://', $_POST['url']) AND !substr_count($_POST['url'], '://')) {
        // Handle URLs that do not have a scheme
        $url = sprintf("%s://%s", 'http', $_POST['url']);
    } else {
        $url = $_POST['url'];
    }

    $input = parse_url($url);

    if (!$input OR !isset($input['host'])) {
        // Either the parsing has failed, or the URL was not absolute
        throw new Exception("Invalid URL");
    } elseif ($input['host'] != 'i.imgur.com') {
        // The host does not match
        throw new Exception("Invalid domain");
    }

    // Prepend URL with scheme, e.g. http://domain.tld
    $host = sprintf("%s://%s", $input['scheme'], $input['host']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: `parse_url()` can fail, therefore you need to make sure it `!== false` before checking `$input['host']`

Comment: @simshaun That is true, but not in the "quick" answer. I've enhanced the answer for you

Comment: ??? Quick answer or not, it's necessary or else you've introduced a potential bug in your code.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to insert http:// dependent on whether its been provided or not?

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease parse_url will only work in full if the URL is absolute, but I have added a sanity check for http/https/ftp

Comment: if you know you are throwing exception why using try? why not handle the exception right there. Exception runs slow.

Comment: @Shiplu It gives one exit point, so makes it easier to handle errors for the front-end. Besides, this could be deeper in the application and you may want to exit completely on certain Exceptions

Answer (score 2):

```
substr($input, 0, strlen('http://i.imgur.com/')) === 'http://i.imgur.com/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this, using [stripos](http://php.net/stripos)

```
if(stripos(trim($url), "http://i.imgur.com")===0){
 // the link is from imgur.com
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url_input = $_POST['input_box_name'];
if ( strpos($url_input, 'http://i.imgur.com/') !== 0 )
```

...

Comment: Needs to be `!== FALSE` or `== 0`. I'd opt for the latter since you would expect it to be act the beginning of the string.

Comment: !== FALSE won't give us the position check, just the presence one. ) And ==0 is just not right, as it'd the same response for FALSE as well.

Comment: I hinted the position check, and that the latter would be better. But yes you are right, it needs to be `=== 0`.  Edit: Just realized you probably meant the condition for throwing an error. Ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways of doing it.. Here's one:

```
if ('http://i.imgur.com/' == substr($link, 0, 19)) {
    ...
}
```